# How to improve indexes in order to get queries executed in milliseconds?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance, mariadb

I have lost the entire night trying to get a better performance on below query without success:

```
    SELECT COUNT(o.id_offer)
      FROM offer o
      JOIN offer_product op
        ON op.id_offer = o.id_offer    
      JOIN advertiser a
        ON a.id_advertiser = o.id_advertiser 
      LEFT 
      JOIN offer_hidden h
        ON h.id_offer = o.id_offer 
       AND h.id_user = 5064
     WHERE o.finality = 'sale' 
       AND h.id_offer IS NULL;
+-------------------+
| COUNT(o.id_offer) |
+-------------------+
|            248250 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (2.80 sec)
```

It is taking about 2 ~ 4 seconds to execute. The application need to perform about 8 ~ 10 similar queries, so, milliseconds execution time is a must.

Explaining the query:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                                           | key                         | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                                |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | offer         | ref    | PRIMARY,fk_offer_advertiser1_idx,fk_offer_finality1_idx | fk_offer_finality1_idx      | 1       | const                        | 167269 | Using index condition                |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | offer_product | ref    | fk_offer_product_offer1_idx                             | fk_offer_product_offer1_idx | 4       | db.offer.id_offer            |      1 | Using index                          |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | advertiser    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY                     | 4       | db.offer.id_advertiser       |      1 | Using index                          |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | offer_hidden  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_offer_hidden_user1_idx                       | PRIMARY                     | 8       | db.offer.id_offer,const      |      1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And `offer`'s indexes (**high cardinality**):

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM offer;
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| offer |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id_offer      | A         |      352683 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| offer |          1 | fk_offer_advertiser1_idx |            1 | id_advertiser | A         |      352683 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| offer |          1 | fk_offer_finality1_idx   |            1 | finality      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

My dev environment currently have about 300 thousand offers and 200 thousand advertisers, but production db have about 8 million and 2 million (respectively) of each one.

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offer;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   327513 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)


    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM advertiser;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   214885 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)
```

Create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `offer` (
  `id_offer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_advertiser` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `date_offer` datetime NOT NULL,
  `finality` enum('buy','sale') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_offer`),
  KEY `fk_offer_advertiser1_idx` (`id_advertiser`),
  KEY `fk_offer_finality1_idx` (`finality`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offer_advertiser1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_advertiser`) REFERENCES `advertiser` (`id_advertiser`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT 1 - [In reply to @Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643794/how-to-improve-indexes-in-order-to-get-queries-executed-in-milliseconds#comment45586898_28643794)**

```
CREATE TABLE `advertiser` (
  `id_advertiser` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_advertiser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `offer_product` (
  `id_offer_product` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_offer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_offer_product`),
  KEY `fk_offer_product_offer1_idx` (`id_offer`),
  KEY `fk_offer_product_product1_idx` (`id_product`),
  KEY `fk_offer_product_offer_product1_idx` (`id_offer`,`id_product`),
  KEY `fk_offer_product_product_offer1_idx` (`id_product`,`id_offer`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offer_product_offer1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_offer`) REFERENCES `offer` (`id_offer`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offer_product_product1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `product` (`id_product`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE `offer_hidden` (
  `id_offer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_offer`,`id_user`),
  KEY `fk_offer_hidden_user1_idx` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_offer_hidden_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Is h.id_offer values ever NULL? (At least when h.id_user = 5064.)

Comment: @jarlh `h.id_offer` is auto incremented. My query verifies if user `5064` hid any offer and ignores these offers when counting total of available offers. So, can be null if user does not have hidden offers, otherwise, any int.

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the question (see edit 1, please).

Comment: What's the point of joining with `advertiser`? At the first glance, the query results should not change if you don't mention `advertiser` in the query at all.

Comment: @Strawberry, could you explain why, please. An `offer` is always linked to exactly one `advertiser` via `offer.id_advertiser`, which is `NOT NULL`. You can't have an `offer` without `advertiser`. The join is `inner`. `advertiser` is not mentioned anywhere else in the query. The number of rows returned by the query should be the same, whether you join with `advertiser` or not. What am I missing?

Comment: @Strawberry, You can't have an offer without advertiser, because `offer.id_advertiser` is `NOT NULL`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I get it too.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Oops, you're right! Unless id_advertiser 0 = 'undefined advertiser' - but I think that would violate the constraint

Comment: I have a lot of offers with advertiser as "0" which means "to future analysis and association to an existing advertiser". This is the point where the confusion started. I get the point of @VladimirBaranov, which said that join is unecessary. A simple `id_advertiser > 0` may help a lot.

Comment: @Strawberry, "Unless id_advertiser 0 = 'undefined advertiser'". There is a `foreign key` defined. So, if `offer` has `id_advertiser` = 0 (or whatever number `NN`), then there must be a row in `advertiser` with `id_advertiser`=0 (or whatever number `NN`). `inner join` would find that row. I would expect that optimizer would detect such things, but apparently MySQL is not that smart. If you add a filter `id_advertiser > 0`, that **would** change the query results.

Comment: Most likely, it will not change performance much, but I would add `CONSTRAINT fk_offer_hidden_offer FOREIGN KEY (id_offer) REFERENCES offer (id_offer)` to the `offer_hidden` table. Of course, only if such constraint really should be there. At the moment its absence looks like an oversight. It may provide an extra hint to the optimizer.

Comment: One more strange thing here is that you are counting not offers, but offer products. In your case `COUNT(o.id_offer)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`. Did you really mean it?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov It doesn't matter as `o.id_offer is not null` anyway.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is normally used.  `COUNT(x)` adds a check for NULL so as to not count cases where `x IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set multi column indexes:

Something like that

```
ALTER  TABLE offer ADD INDEX(finality, id_offer, id_advertiser);
ALTER  TABLE offer_product ADD INDEX(id_offer);
ALTER  TABLE advertiser ADD INDEX(id_advertiser);
ALTER  TABLE offer_hidden ADD INDEX(id_offer, id_user);
```

This way, your search will first retrieve offers by finality, and then doing the join, using indexes for each table

Answer (score 0):

```
-- covering index access to 'offer'
-- (and, perhaps, better caching for 'offer_product' too)
ALTER TABLE offer ADD INDEX(finality, id_offer, id_advertiser);

SELECT COUNT(o.id_offer)
FROM (
    -- do 'left join' first to minimize number of rows
    -- before scanning 'offer_product' and 'advertiser'
    SELECT offer.id_offer, offer.id_advertiser
    FROM offer
    LEFT JOIN offer_hidden h ON
        h.id_offer = offer.id_offer
        AND h.id_user = 5064
    WHERE
        offer.finality = 'sale'
        AND h.id_offer IS NULL
) o
JOIN offer_product op ON
    op.id_offer = o.id_offer
JOIN advertiser a ON
    a.id_advertiser = o.id_advertiser
;
```